Looping if statement if
I am trying to write a "rock paper scisours game" in C#, and I wanted to add a "choose a name screen".
namespace Program;
public class Program() {
    static void Main(string[] args){
        Console.WriteLine("Wilkommen Benutzer zu Schere, Stein, Papier!");
        Console.WriteLine("Möchtest du einen Namen wählen? (j/n) ");
        string? choice1 = Console.ReadLine();
        if(choice1 == "j"){
            Console.WriteLine("Dann wähle deinen Namen! ");
            string? name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(name + ", ist das so richtig? (j/n) ");
            string? choiceName = Console.ReadLine();
            if(choiceName == "n"){
                //Repeat "if(choice1 == "j")" here
            }
            else if(choiceName == "j"){
                Console.WriteLine("Wilkommen " + name + "!")
            }
        }
        else if(choice1 == "n"){
            Console.WriteLine("Dann wird dir der Name \"Benutzer\" zugeteilt");
            name = "Benutzer";
        }    
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("Ich nehme das als ein Nein")
            Console.WriteLine("Dann wird dir der Name \"Benutzer\" zugeteilt");
            name = "Benutzer";
        }
    }
}

At line 13 is where I want it to go back or repeat line 7 until the user types "j".
I can't think logically enough to use a while statement. Is there anything else I could do to repeat the if code?
PS. I am new to C# and programming in general.

You can use a do-while statement, the block of code will be repeated as long as choiceName isn't j.
string? name, choiceName;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Dann wähle deinen Namen! ");
    name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(name + ", ist das so richtig? (j/n) ");
    choiceName = Console.ReadLine();
}
while(choiceName != "j");

Console.WriteLine("Wilkommen " + name + "!");

You can also wrap the process into a method.
static bool ChooseName(out string name)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Dann wähle deinen Namen! ");
    name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(name + ", ist das so richtig? (j/n) ");
    return Console.ReadLine() == "j";
}

while(!ChooseName(out string name)) {}
Console.WriteLine("Wilkommen " + name + "!");

